# How to change the width of a messageCell depending on the length of the message? in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have code written where if my message I send is more than one line it resizes to fit the entire message. However, if the message is something like "ok" then it will be sent within a long oval, which as you may imagine, does not make sense. Below is a picture of what I mean. In conclusion, I am looking for a solution to allow the message cells to resize horizontally to correctly fit the text.

[image: What the message cell looks like right now]

Comment: 1st you didn't say wether your using a TableViewController or a CollectionViewController. Resizing the way you want works differently for both of them. 2nd you didn't add any code so how can anyone figure out why that oval thing is happening. Its impossible to figure either of those out without more info. Screen shots and show what's in your tableView's cellForRow or collectionView's cellForItem delegate methods and if your using a custom cell show that too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set the constraints like this.
[image]

Set the content hugging and content compression resistance priority

[image]

Then click the right constraint and change the horizontal space constraint priority.
[image]